# What is the pattern matching expression for KA-05-AA-0000 in html pattern attribute?

Tags: html, pattern-matching

What is The Regular expression for pattern matching KA-05-AA-0000?

Comment: It would be \KA-([0-9]){2}-([A-Z]){2}-([0-9]){4}\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9]-[A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/g

```
[A-Z] Match a single character present in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) case sensitive)
- matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
[0-9] Match a single character present in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
```